# Proving axiom consistency

Tags: constructive-mathematics

I am trying to prove that some preconditions don't introduce an inconsistency to my (constructive) system. I would like to know if this is possible with the set-up below, and how to do this, and what additionally i need to include/specify to make this happen. What do I need to specify about `isThisTrue`?

```
Inductive myThing : Type :=
  | a : myThing
  | b : myThing.

Inductive isThisTrue : myThing -> Prop :=
  | is_a : isThisTrue a
  | is_b : isThisTrue b.

Definition somethingIsTrue := ~ (forall x, ~ isThisTrue x).

Definition nothingIsFalse := forall x, ~~ isThisTrue x.
```

So, I want show something like -

`Definition consistent := somethingIsTrue /\ nothingIsFalse ...` does not introduce inconsistency

Comment: The idea is that we have no additional information about `isThisTrue`, but we want to say something about the conjunction of the two propositions `somethingIsTrue` and `nothingIsFalse`, showing that they dont contradict themselves or each other. But for that we need some additional assumptions about `isThisTrue` or maybe a complete re-statement of the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by “does not introduce inconsistency”? We are simply introducing new notation. How would that create inconsistency?

Comment: My first thought would be to try to prove that `~ ~ somethingIsTrue /\ nothingIsFalse`, which would be trivial for example, if I was instead proving `~~ (somethingIsTrue \/ ~ somethingIsTrue)`. My goal is to prove additional results implied by `somethingIsTrue /\ nothingIsFalse` but I am not sure that these two do not contradict each other (I actually have slightly different definitions which are more involved, but I am interested in how I would approach this in general)

Comment: Perhaps I could scrap the definition of `isThisTrue` and parametrize `somethingIsTrue` and `nothingIsFalse`, so that I would instead try to prove something like, `exists (isThisTrue : myThing -> Prop), (somethingIsTrue isThisTrue /\ nothingIsFalse isThisTrue)`